# Flex: Negative number wordwrap in mx:TextArea

Tags: apache-flex, textarea, flex3, word-wrap

Version: Flex SDK3.5

Example code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" backgroundColor="0xFFFFFF" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
     <s:TextArea width="280" height="200"
        text="The hzy_text should be integer between -2147483648 and 2147483647. Please input again."/>
     <mx:TextArea width="280" height="200"
        text="The hzy_text should be integer between -2147483648 and 2147483647. Please input again."/>
</mx:Application>
```

[the screenshot](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4942690#4942690)(sorry, i do not have permission to upload image, you can see in this url:http://forums.adobe.com/message/4942690#4942690)

When i use mx:TextArea, it wraps "-2147483648" to "-" "2147483648".

Use s:TextArea, it wraps right.

But i use sdk3.5, can not use spark components, how to solve this problem in mx?

Thanks for any help!